# Unable to run py.test from command line when using a marker and text fixture option

Tags: python, pytest

I set up the fixture like this:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--env', action='store', default='qa', 
                     help='Specify environment: "qa", "aws", "prod".')

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def testenv(request):
    return request.config.getoption('--env')
```

And this works when I call py.test against a filename, for example:

- py.test -v --env prod functionaltests/test_health_apps.py

But it does not work when I invoke py.test with markers, as with the following variations:

- py.test -m selenium --env prod
- py.test -m 'selenium' --env prod
- py.test --env prod -m selenium
- py.test --env prod -m 'selenium'

These return:

Usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]

py.test: error: no such option: --env

Are markers and command line options incompatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are compatible. My guess will be that your configuration file (`conftest.py`) is not in the same directory as where you launch your tests from. (I might be wrong here)

My suggestion will be to create separate file for configurations:

```
#configs.py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--env', 
    dest='testenv',
    choices=["qa","aws","prod"],
    default='qa', 
    help='Specify environment: "qa", "aws", "prod".')

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def testenv(request):
    return request.config.option.testenv
```

and create the `runner.py` that you'll be using as `py.test` command:

```
#runner.py
import pytest
import sys
import configs

def main():    
    plgns = [configs]
    pytest.main(sys.argv[1:], plugins=plgns)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

then you can start as `python runner.py --env prod -m selenium`
This works for me very well.

Comment: Thanks Alex, this did the trick. conftest.py is in the same directory as the test files; I put runner.py in the root directory, though, so I could avoid having to use its path for the command line instruction.